# How to apply a specific CSS for a item in a v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I have an array of objects which contains a name and an id.
I'm using a `v-for` directive to iterate through those objects and display their name.
When I click on one of the `<li>`, it calls a method which stores in a data variable the id of the object selected.
I'm trying to apply a specific CSS class for this selected item (Applying a grey background in order to tell the user it's currently selected)
Since it's considered an anti-pattern to mix `v-for` and `v-if`, I'm currently looking for another alternative.

I've tried to call a method with the current item as an argument, and return a class like `"CommonItemClass SelectedClass"` if the current item == the selected item (stored with `@click`). Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
<ol>         
 <li @click="selectedCategorie(categorie)" v-for="categorie in categories" :key="categorie.id" :class="methodClass(categorie)">
  {{ categorie.nom }}             
 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: have you tried making it a computed instead of a method that you call?

Comment: @LShapz yes but the thing is with computed() I can't throw the current item as an argument so there is no way to know which item is the current one

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

In your template:

```html
<ol>
    <li
        :key="categorie.id"
        v-for="categorie in categories"
        :class="{ 'selected': selectedId === categorie.id }"
        @click="selectedId = categorie.id"
    >{{ categorie.nom }}</li>
</ol>
```

In your javascript

```
data() {
    return {
        categories: [...],
        selectedId: null
    };
}
```

In your styles

```
li.selected {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: @Poudreuse If this resolved your issue, please [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left.